# How to res.json and res.render at the same time, pass mongo db to angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I use express, which comes with jade template engine.
**app.js**

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

for each template, I will need to have `res.render` to have the html header rendered, if I don't use `res.render`, the template/page won't show. **routes/index.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Bookshop' });
});

router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('data', { title: 'Bookshop | Categories' });
});

router.get('/items', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('items', { title: 'Bookshop | Items' });
});
```

in **app.js** I've got my MongoDB set up correctly.

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('book', ['books']);
```

What I am going to achieve is to pass MongoDB database to angular, then loop in jade file. **myscript.js**

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('/data').then(function(res){
        console.log(res.data);
        $scope.books = res.data;
    });
});
```

**data.jade** file looks like this

```
p(ng-repeat="item in books")
    span {{item.name}}
    span {{item.barcode}}
    span {{item.price}}
```

Right now I am stuck on how to pass database to **myscript.js**. I am unable to do this way in **app.js**

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
     db.zero.find(function (err, docs) {
        res.json(docs)
    });
});
```

the reason is jade template is being used, and need to use `res.render` to get the page showed correctly, however if I use `router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('data', { title: 'Bookshop | Categories' });
    });` I am unable to pass database.

I understand I am unable to use res.render and res.json the at same time. is there a solution for pass database to angular? or do I have to convert jade to html? I am sure if I use html file I can use `res.json`

Thanks

Comment: You can not do both. `res.json` send only the data where as `res.render` will render the template passed to render method. What you want? can you explain?

Comment: I need to pass DB to angular, but if I don't have res.render, my page got errors. how ever looks like only res.json can send DB successfully, so if there is a way to have template render also pass DB thanks

Comment: What do you mean by pass DB to angular? I can already see you are passing documents from mongo DB back to your client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. `res.render()` renders a template and send it to the client. The response `Content-Type` header when using `res.render()` would be `text/html` for example. But `res.json()` sends data in `json` format to the client, thus the `Content-Type` header for the response will be `application/json`.

**UPDATE**

You have to create two routes in order to achieve what you want. The first route will render your jade template. And in order to retrieve data from server as JSON in Angular controller you need to use another route. For example:

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('data', { title: 'Bookshop | Categories' });
});

router.get('/data.json', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.myCollection.find(function (err, docs) {
        if(err) {
            // Handle error
        } else {
            res.json({title: 'Data', 'mydata': docs});
        }
    });
});
```

And in the Angular controller you use the second route like below:

```
$http.get('/data.json').then(function(res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks if I don't use `res.render()`, only use `res.json` the page looks like a broken page. as you can see that I have `'mydata': docs` , is there a way to get Angular to get `mydata` variable ? Thanks

Comment: @olo Updated my answer

Comment: but if we don't use render, how do we have Content-Type header as I use jade.

Comment: @olo When you use the `res.json()` express itself will set the content type to `application/json` for you. When you use `res.render()` express will load and render the template with the given data and sends it to the client along with a `text/html` content type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can get databae if I use res.json. however jade template needs res.render. I can't get the template/page displayed.  I don't think this question I made it very clear, but I create a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331499/if-res-render-is-being-used-how-to-use-res-json I think it is more clear than this one

Comment: @olo If this is not an answer to your problem, you must edit your question to clarify your problem. See my updated answer for what exactly you meant in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer, that is exactly what I want. much appreciated

Comment: I didn't know I need to create another one like `router.get('/data.json'` to get the database passed. so I think `router.get('/data.json ...` -< this /name can be anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work and catch data from Angular JS end...In Node JS `res` means one type of `return` so you can not return two times in a single block.

```
 router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
        var db = req.db;
        db.myCollection.find(function (err, docs) {


         if(err) {
            res.send(err);
           }
        else{

            res.send({ title: 'Data', 'mydata': docs }); 
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get Mongo database, if I use this method. the object I get is like html stuff.